# Determine linear independence when....

Tags: discrete-mathematics

let , $ys=-(x_1t_1+...+x_nt_n)$

If $y\not= 0$, then

$s=-(1/y)(x_1t_1+...+x_nt_n)$

$s=(-x_1/y)t_1+...+(-x_n/y)t_n$

Thus, $s \in \operatorname{span}(x_1,...,x_n)$

Is my proof correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct.  If $a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_kv_k + bw=0$ **and** $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_k, w \}$ **is a linearly independent set**, then you know each and every coefficient (including $b$) is equal to $0$.  That's the definition of linear independence.

So what you want to do is assume that $w \in \operatorname{span} (v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ and arrive at a contradiction (by finding a non-trivial linear combination of a linearly independent set that's equal to $0$).  The answer above shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Actually, $w\notin\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$. Otherwise, there would be scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ such that $w=\alpha_1v_1+\cdots\alpha_kv_k$. But then$$1\times w-\alpha_1v_1-\cdots-\alpha_kv_k,$$and therefore (since $1\ne0$) the set $\{w,v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ would be linearly dependent.